# Limitar quantidade de caractere em um textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, eu estou tentando "criar" um sistema de "captcha" para meu programa, porém ele as vezes excede o limite do textbox, e nesse caso o usuário não saberia o que vem a seguir, pesquisei muito, porém ainda não encontrei nem uma solução, estarei deixando um pouco do código abaixo, e agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

```
Random random = new Random();
tb_noRobot.MaxLength = 1;
tb_noRobot.Text = Criptography.GerarHashMd5(random.Next().ToString());
```

Observação: "criptography" é o método padrão de gerar o hash dos valores.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que você pretende... nem o sentido de gerar uma guid para exibir apenas o primeiro caractere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu método retorna uma `String` você pode eliminar os caracteres seguites a quantidade que quiser, por exemplo, limitar a 5 caracteres:

```
Random random = new Random();
tb_noRobot.MaxLength = 1;
tb_noRobot.Text = Criptography.GerarHashMd5(random.Next().ToString()).Substring(0,5); //retorna os 5 primeiros caracteres, só alterar o '5' para a qtd necessária.
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, provavelmente isso vai ajudar muito, ainda sou novo na área, não sabia que era possível algo assim...